# Fixed navbar with double rows?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to display 8 options to the user in a nav-bar, I want to have 2 rows of 8. I want all the options to be fixed to the bottom of the screen and the user to be able to see all 8 at all times.

At the moment , my second row is hidden behind my first?

```css
.navbar-default {
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    background: #f9f9f9;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-top: none;

    text-transform: uppercase;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
    -khtml-box-shadow: 0 4px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 4px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 4px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
    box-shadow: 0 4px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    margin: 0 20px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #D13030;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: .02em;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -ms-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
    background-color: #E74C3C;
    color: #f9f9f9;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.15s linear;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.15s linear;
    -ms-transition: background-color 0.15s linear;
    -o-transition: background-color 0.15s linear;
    transition: background-color 0.15s linear;
}
```

```html
<!-- NAVIGATION BAR -->
  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom" role="navigation">
    <div class="container text-center">
      <div class="row">
        <a href="about.html">
          <div class="col-sm-3" id="about-tab">About</div>
        </a>
        <a href="specifying.html">
          <div class="col-sm-3" id="about-tab">Specifying</div>
        </a>
        <a href="market-sectors.html">
          <div class="col-sm-3" id="about-tab">Market Sectors</div>
        </a>
        <a href="about.html">
          <div class="col-sm-3" id="about-tab">Shop</div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: do you already have some CSS written that people can work off? If so please add to your question.

Comment: What's not working with your code?

Comment: create a fiddle of your codes.

Comment: Seems to work fine: http://www.bootply.com/DsthXbmVrz

Answer (score 0):

See I could not find 8 option in your `navbar`, but to place it at bottom of page you can use code as below. Add this in your `navbar-default`

```
.navbar-default {
position:fixed;
bottom:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want 2 rows at the bottom of your page right?

```
<div class="first-row">
    <button>menu1</button>
    <button>menu2</button>
    <button>menu3</button>
    <button>menu4</button>
</div>
<div class="second-row">
    <button>menu5</button>
    <button>menu6</button>
    <button>menu7</button>
    <button>menu8</button>
</div>
```

in the css:

```
.first-row{
    position:fixed;
    height:50px; /*or anything you like*/
    bottom: 100px;
}
.second-row{
    position:fixed;
    height:50px; /*or anything you like*/
    bottom: 50px;
}
```

The 2 rows will be on the bottom of your page.